# How to apply accelerometer on a pivot page in WP7 to navigate the pages?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, pivot, accelerometer

How to apply accelerometer on a pivot page in WP7 to navigate the pivot pages?

Like when i tilt the phone to the right, it will navigate the page to the right, and vice versa when i tilt it to the left.

Answer (score 3):

The accelerometer readings can be detected by handling the `AccelerometerReadingChanged` event as described in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604984.aspx

You then need to apply some sort of threshold to the values that are returned in the event arguments. When a suitable threshold has been exceeded, increment or decrement in the pivot index, i.e. `pivot.SelectedIndex++`

Answer (score 0):

While the approach ColinE suggested would undoubtedly work, it's somewhat messy.  You'd have to calculate the threasholds yourself and you're getting a much lower level reading off the sensor than what you need.

I would suggest using the OrientationChanged event supported by the Page control.

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Orientation)
    {
        case PageOrientation.Portrait:
        case PageOrientation.PortraitDown:
        case PageOrientation.PortraitUp:
            contentPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
            break;
        case PageOrientation.Landscape:
        case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            contentPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the questions asks how to change pivot index on phone tilt rather than orientation change